# bring sliding menu from right to left , that covers only one part of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I my application, I have a button (on right) on `navigation bar`. When a user clicks on that button, a new view gets pushed in from right to left, and it needs to cover only half of the screen.

It needs to have only 3 things - Call, Email and Home. On pressing one of them, corresponding thing happens.

I went through several libraries, but I am not able to follow any. I need something very simple, but they seem to be very complex. can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Which library did you use? What about it didn't make sense? Your question is currently too broad.

Comment: i tried using SWRevealViewController and a couple of others. they seem too complex.. i am a new iOS developer..

Comment: They have sample projects, did you run those to see how it works and look at the code?

Comment: yes.. i am trying to do that again.. getting a little bit.. after going through it twice..

Comment: Will try it out again and then get back to you..

Comment: @Wain: all libraries that in am going though require their class to be installed as root view controller of window, but i cannot do that. are their any librraies that do not have this criterion??

Comment: Why can't you do that ?

Comment: in my app, i am using a tabBarController that is presented from anotherViewController.. and i have this requirement of "Silent Login" for which  I am already switching rootViewControllers twice in my application.. the third one will make it very complicated..!!

Comment: do you want me to elaborate what i am doing in app and when i am switching controllers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45984/discussion-between-wain-and-coder123)

Answer (score 0):

Use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:] but not all the application support url scheme and you do not need to push the controller just animate view like push effect!